# CreateProcess with low z-order

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi, createprocess

On Windows, (using C++, in case it matters):

From a GUI application `A` I use [`CreateProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa) to start up an external GUI application `B`.

It seems that Windows automatically brings the newly started program `B` to front (i.e. topmost window). I would like to suppress this behavior so that `B`'s windows are *not* moved to front - instead they simply should stay behind the windows of program `A`.

I discovered that `CreateProcess` accepts a [`STARTUPINFO`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/ns-processthreadsapi-startupinfoa) where you can specify `wShowWindow` in connection with `STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW`. However, even specifying [`SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE` or `SW_SHOWNA`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-showwindow) does not keep the window in background - the window is not activated, but still comes to front.

**TLRD** Is there a way to start an external GUI application so that the newly started program does not come to front?

Comment: Create a desktop and start it there

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Then the user would not see it in the taskbar, right?

Comment: are `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE` not do what you want ?

Comment: @RbMm `SW_SHOWMINNOACTIVE ` displays the window in minimized state. I already thought about this (even about `SW_HIDE`), but I would prefer the windows to open in normal size and position - just behind existing windows. So it might be *closest possible* to what I want, it is not what I'd *actually* like.

Comment: Realistically that's probably the closest that you can robustly achieve.

Comment: Presumably, the goal is to launch a GUI process without disrupting the user. That's likely not going to happen. You can pick: Either have the newly created process' window come to the top of the Z-order, or have the newly created process' taskbar button flash.

Comment: @phimuemue Assuming B opens a normal window, you could maybe set A to topmost, run B and wait for its window to open (behind A's), then SetWindowPos back to non-topmost again. This could still cause some back-and-forth activation and perhaps even z-order flashing, But the only way to completely avoid that would be installing a (temp) global hook, which is rather heavy handed.

Comment: @phimuemue Have you checked [`SetWindowPos`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowpos#return-value) to see if it helps?

Comment: @dxiv @RitaHan-MSFT I already thought about this, but decided against it: Reliably waiting for another program to open a window is afaik not trivial. What should `A` do if `B` takes ages to load (the user interacting in the meantime) or even crashes before showing its first window? It seems to be a solution more intrusive than I'd like.

Comment: @phimuemue Is *GUI application B* your own or third-party application?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Ideally I was looking for a solution compatible with both own and third-party application. But if there are techniques specific to one or the other, I am glad to learn about these.

Comment: @phimuemue `A` doesn't have to wait for `B` to show its window to continue its work. `A` can use a separate thread to monitor `B` start up progress. And it is not suggested to control other application's window behavior but you can control your own, like using `BringWindowToTop` to put your own application window to top most in z-order.

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT Surely another thread can do the waiting so that `A` stays responsive for the user. But it seems non-trivial (regardless of which thread does it) to reliably determine if `B` has opened a window.

Comment: Isn't it just a call to [WaitForInputIdle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-waitforinputidle)?